# JSON.net deserialize JSON without schema

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have some JSON:

```
{
    "739c39e": [7866679, 31.96051, 117.13700, 310, 30100, 408, 20515, 2955, "A319", "B-6429", 1440504861, "SHA", "XIY", "MU2168", 0, 0, "CES2168", 0],   
    "739d433": [5242971, 51.46741, -0.48536, 270, 0, 16, 0, 2529, "A320", "T7-MRD", 1440504861, "LHR", "BEY", "ME202", 1, 0, "MEA202", 0]
}
```

I am trying to deserialize this, but am not having much luck.

I've tried:

```
 var definition = new { a = "", b = "", c = "", d = "", e = "", f = "", g = "", h = "", i = "", j = "", k = "", l = "", m = "", n = "", o = "", p = "", q = "", r = "" };
 var jsonData = @File.ReadAllText(@filepathToData);
 dynamic deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonData, definition);
```

I never expected that to work, really, as there is no "definition" in the JSON.
I have also tried the `JArray.Parse(jsonData);` way, but I get nothing.

I've also tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);` but that does not return anything... or at least I am unable to inspect the returned object with Visual Studio (2015).

Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm doing this in Unity3D, if it makes any difference.

Comment: Your data is a Dictionary, but your defeinition is an array. So change it maybe to something like this:
var definition = new Dictionary( string key, new{a = "", b......}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object[]>>(json);
o.Dump();
```

Comment: Nice one, thank you! @Edgaras was on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

You could deserialize it into a dynamic object like this:

```
dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(o["739c39e"]);
Console.WriteLine(o["739c39e"][3]); // output: 310
```